# Encoding Query Parameters from API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, encode

I have an created a REST application in nodejs and also I have configured API gateway for the URLs. I have a URL with query parameters. When one request from postman with query params with special characters like +,\ , then I need to encode these from API gateway. Is it possible to do that? Someone please help with an answer...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had a chance to try given solution ?

Answer (score 1):

We need to override the query parameter in `mapping template` of `IntegrationRequest`, function we need in vtl is `$util.urlEncode`.

The moment we start overriding, we need to ensure to build entire request body, parameters, etc.

Template from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-examples-mapping-templates), i just added one additional function `$util.urlEncode` call to encode parameters. If query parameter value is `Test4!` it will be changed to `Test4%21`

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
  "params" : {
    #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
    "$type" : {
      #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
      "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($util.urlEncode($params.get($paramName)))"
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
      #end
    }
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
}
```

[image]