# Aws ApiGateway wrong decode querystring

Tags: amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-api-gateway, query-string, decoding

i'm having some problems with Aws Api Gateway query string decoding. i have an Endpoint that accept params like the following, but for some reason the "**=**" inside the brackets is wrong decoded. this is a problem because i need to pass conditions like "**>=**" and "**<=**" as shown in the third example.

- `conditions[price]=20`

  - `conditions[price]=20`

    - `{"conditions": {"price":"20"}}`
- `conditions[price >]=20`

  - `conditions[price%20%3E]=20`

    - `{"conditions": {"price >":"20"}}`
- `conditions[price >=]=20`

  - `conditions[price%20%3E%3D]=20`

    - **`{"conditions_price_":">]=20"}`**
- `conditions[price =]=20`

  - conditions[price%20%3D]=20

    - **`{"conditions_price_":"]=20}`**

special character are encoded in standard http encoding  (**percentage encoding**) as shown.

as i can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66102140/encoding-query-parameters-from-api-gateway) it is possible override decoding rules, but i prefer don't touch AWS configurations

do you have any idea?

Comment: `conditions[price >=]=20` feels and looks terrible. Apart from that it is unclear to me what your API gets called with, what currently happens vs. what is supposed to happen. What specifically is not working? And why do you have query strings that are this weird?

Comment: my API is developed on cakePHP 2.x which accepts as parameter the format conditions[price >=]=20. this parameter allows us to filter the results with the same or higher price, therefore to avoid manipulating the input data and to define a new logic to represent the parameter ">=" we want to use the same syntax.